# Decision box for a flowchart with some text properly wrapped inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to generate a standard decision box for a flowchart but it needs to do the following:

1. Behave like a standard HTML button where I can set the caption/value and is 'clickable'.
2. Be able to scale the decision box size based on the length of the text input.
3. So lets say the normally rectangular text box fits perfectly within the outer decision box. The problem is the space on all four sides of the text box that is wasted. I can't think of a good way to use that space in a better way and make my decision box smaller that way.

I have tried using a background decision shape image with text box overlay as well as patching two triangle shapes to make the decision box shape and then overlay a text box on top of it, but they all seem to be unusually complicated means to get this simple decision box.

Added the code samples below....its probably not correct as I haven't gotten it to display the text box on top of the decision box yet... but even if this works, my problem about the space usage for text wraping inside the decision box is still not resolved.

I'm more comfortable with HTML/CSS than Javascript but would not mind either of them if explained.

Here is the CSS for the two triangle shapes I am using although its not complete yet.

====== CSS ===

```
.triangles{
width: 160;
height:150;
z-index:1;
}

.decisiontext{
position:relative
left:0px;
top:-50px;
z-index:2;
}

#left-triangle {
width: 30;
height: 0px;
float:left;
border-right: 79px solid orange;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;

-webkit-transform: rotate(0.05deg);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: rotate(0.05deg); /* Didn't check Opera yet */
transform: rotate(0.05deg);
}
#right-triangle {
 width: 40;
 height: 0;
 float:left;
 border-left: 79px solid red;
 border-top: 50px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;

-webkit-transform: rotate(0.05deg);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: rotate(0.05deg); 
transform: rotate(0.05deg);
}
```

====== Here is the html==============

```
  <div class="decisionbox">

      <div id="left-triangle"; class="triangles">
      <!-- end .left-triangle -->
      </div>        
      <div id="right-triangle"; class="triangles">
      <!-- end .right-triangle --></div>   

      <div class="decisiontext">

      <button type="button" style=" max-width:100px; white-space:normal; font-    size:10px">I am using the regular button here but needs something that uses space inside         the decision box better.</button>  

      <!-- end .decisiontext -->
      </div>

  <!-- end .decisionbox -->
  </div>
```

===============================

Comment: Some code you've tried and/or an image of what you are trying to accomplish would be great here.

Comment: Here are the jsFiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/BJh9F/

Comment: Hi Fong-Wan Chau, thanks for that link.  I am going to use this next time as well.  Cheers!